Inversion of Nonlinear Dynamic using Koopman Operator
Consider a nonlinear dynamical system $X_{k+1}=F(X_k)$，to solve this system,we can transfer $X$ to a Koopman Invariant Subspace using a set of observation functions 'g' like $$g(X_{k+1})=K\mathcal g(X_k)$$ where 'K' is a Koopman Operator.
But for some typical systems such as Hamilton Systems,these kind of systems have a zero eigenvalue for their Koopman Operator(and the eigenfunction corresponding to the zero eigenvalue is exactly the Hamiltonian function of the system), and if a matrix has a zero eigenvalue, then there is not exist an inverse matrix for it. My confusion is, how the system inverse in this space while there is not exist a $K^{-1}$ so that $$g(X_k)=K^{-1}\mathcal g(X_{k+1})$$

Never heard of a Koopman operator so I’ll be learning something new with the answers.

I think you might be confusing the Koopman generator with the Koopman operator. The Hamiltonian function $H$ satisfies $H(x_k)= H(x_{k+1}) = KH(x_k)$ since the quantity is conserved. This corresponds to an eigenvalue of $1$.

@Aruralreader : Broadly, there is a relation between points on a manifold and maximal ideals of some function rings (algebraic geometry has more general ideas) over this manifold. The dynamic on the point level induces a dynamic on the function level. The latter is less accessible but linear, thus Koopman operator, so one can look for smaller invariant subspaces of the function space, explore eigenvalues etc.

Thank you kindly for the explanation @LutzLehmann.
